# Clickonce Publish Fail

Tags: .net, iis, clickonce

When I go to publish I get a remote server returned an error 404 not found.

I have my publishing folder location set to: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp
Installation folder url: http://localhost/myapp

Can someone guide me to how I can fix this issue

Comment: As far as I know, the 404 error means the page not found. You say you get a remote server returned an error 404.Do you use the "http://localhost/myapp" to access the clickonce application? The localhost means the localside, if you want to access remote server, you should use remote server's IP address.

Comment: yes, I'm using localhost/myapp

Comment: Could you please tell me what the deployment web page you have used for you clickonce publish? Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXAQ9.png) shows.